# Python Array with percentage bar

Tags: python

I would like to code in Python the following Image.
I know mostly matplotlib but I'm open to use new package if necessary.
Does anyone knows how to do something like this in Python ? For me it looks like something I've never seen before to be honest.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pyqt5 can provide you this:

```
import random
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QProgressBar, QVBoxLayout

class Actions(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        maxi = max(list_.values())
        for el in list_:
            bar = QProgressBar(self)
            bar.setRange(0, maxi)
            bar.setFormat(f"{el}: {list_[el]}mg (%p%)")
            bar.setValue(list_[el])
            layout.addWidget(bar)
        self.show()
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_ = {
        "Vitamin A": 902,
        "Vitamin B1": 350,
        "Vitamin B2": 420,
        "Vitamin B3": 15.83,
        "Vitamin B5": 2.94,
    }
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Actions()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Indeed you need to add theme, colors and other thing to have good render.

[image]